# Programacion funcional. Arreglos

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Arreglo {
    double[] values = {3.3,1.2,4.6,8.9,10.0,14.0,13.2,11.8,9.9,1.0};
    *DoubleSummaryStatistics summary* = Arrays.stream(values).summaryStatistics();
    System.out*.*printf("*Min: %f", summary.getMin*());
    System.out*.*printf("*Max: %f", summary.getMax*());
    System.out*.*printf("*Sum: %f", summary.getSum*());
    *System.out*.*printf("Average: %f", summary*.getAverage());
```

Buenas tardes compañer@s me salen algunos errores no se porque si me pueden ayudar por favor, estoy utilizando el IDE Eclipse.

Comment: el texto que esta entre astericos so los errores que me salen

Comment: y que error sale ?

Comment: En la fila que inicia con Doubles sale esto:Multiple markers at this line
 - DoubleSummaryStatistics cannot be resolved to 
  a type
 - Arrays cannot be resolved.

Comment: En el resto de filas sale esto: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - Syntax error on tokens, FormalParameter expected 
  instead
 - Syntax error on token ""Min: %f"", invalid 
  FormalParameterList.

Comment: En la ultima fila sale esto: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ""Average: %f"", invalid 
  FormalParameterList
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Answer (score 1):

asegurate de estar corriendo el proyecto con Java 8 o superior. Yo acabo de hacer un test y funciona sin problema el código.

```
@Test
public void test(){
    double[] values = {3.3,1.2,4.6,8.9,10.0,14.0,13.2,11.8,9.9,1.0};
    final DoubleSummaryStatistics summary = Arrays.stream(values).summaryStatistics();
    System.out.printf("*Min: %f", summary.getMin());
    System.out.printf("*Max: %f", summary.getMax());
    System.out.printf("*Sum: %f", summary.getSum());
    System.out.printf("Average: %f", summary.getAverage());
}
```

Y esta es la respuesta...

```
*Min: 1.000000*Max: 14.000000*Sum: 77.900000Average: 7.790000
```

Comment: como puedo verificar eso???

Comment: java --version, o mira la configuración del IDE que estés usando.